# Program type already present: com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.runtime.ThrowableExtension

Tags: android

When I enable building with Java 1.8 my build step `transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug` fails with this error:

```
Program type already present: com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.runtime.ThrowableExtension$ConcurrentWeakIdentityHashMap$WeakKey
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.runtime.ThrowableExtension$ConcurrentWeakIdentityHashMap$WeakKey, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

I'm quite desperate, I don't know how to debug this, what should I try/examine, etc. Of course I've tried clean build.

My setup:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
```

I'm also using Kotlin. The project is not small, I can't replicate it in clean project with same dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved this. This is a bug in google vr library (`com.google.vr:sdk-videowidget`) - we use an older version because the newer has higher minimal SDK Api requirement. The buggy one was `1.80.0`, the fix is in `1.130.0`.

I've discovered this by https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69835550 - directly searching in Google's issue tracker, sadly it wasn't indexed in Google search. Lib issue: https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-android-sdk/issues/513

Answer (score 0):

This problems usually stems when the same dependency is implemented twice.

To look for conflicts run in adnroid studio's terminal the follwing

```
./gradlew app:dependencies
```

if you are on linux or

```
gradlew app:dependencies
```

if you are on widows

now look for conflicts:

if you see a library depended upon more than once look of "old-verion -> new-version" if you see it then gradle will solve this conflict for you, if you don't then that's the library you need to exclude from either libraries that depend on it using the line below.

The solution is to excluded the dependency that's implemented twice using the following line in your app gradle file

```
implementation ("<whatever>") {
    exclude module: '<conflict library>'
}
```

Comment: Well, I'm afraid that the type `ThrowableExtension` is not from a dependency, but from a toolchain when the desugaring is somehow done twice? Maybe in some dependency and the throwable extension is again brought in my build processes?